# Java read in single file and write out multiple files

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I want to write a simple java program to read in a text file and then write out a new file whenever a blank line is detected. I have seen examples for reading in files but I don't know how to detect the blank line and output multiple text files.

**fileIn.txt:**

```
line1
line2

line3
```

**fileOut1.txt:**

```
line1
line2
```

**fileOut2.txt:**

```
line3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case your file has **special characters**, maybe you should specify the **encoding**.

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("fileIn.txt"));
InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
int n = 0;
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("fileOut" + ++n + ".txt", "UTF-8");
for (String line;(line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = new PrintWriter("file" + ++n + ".txt", "UTF-8");
    } else {
        out.println(line);
    }
}
out.flush();
out.close();
reader.close();
streamReader.close();
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks! I don't really understand the for loop though. I'm used to the for(initialization; termination; increment). Why is it not String line = null; and there is not increment?

Comment: Are optional. You can have only `for(;;)`

Answer (score 1):

You can detect an empty string to find out if a line is blank or not. For example:

```
if(str!=null && str.trim().length()==0)
```

Or you can do (if using JDK 1.6 or later)

```
if(str!=null && str.isEmpty())
```

Comment: Your two conditions are not equivalent. `isEmpty()` only checks for length, it does not trim previously

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - That was an oversight on my part. Added the null check as well!

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to detect the blank line..

```
if (line.trim().length==0) { // perform 'new File' behavior
```

> .. and output multiple text files.

Do what is done for a single file, in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
String line;
int empty = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
 // Line is empty
 }
}
```

The above code snippet can be used to detect if the line is empty and at that point you can create [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) to write to new file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        writeToMultipleFiles("src/main/resources/fileIn.txt", "src/main/resources/fileOut.txt");
    }

    private static void writeToMultipleFiles(String fileIn, String fileOut) throws Exception {      

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(fileIn))));
        String line;
        int counter = 0;
        BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(fileOut))));

        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){

            if(line.trim().length()!=0){
                wr.write(line);
                wr.write("\n");
            }else{
                wr.close();
                wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileOut + counter)));
                wr.write(line);
                wr.write("\n");
            }
            counter++;
        }

        wr.close();
    }
```