# files are empty when writing multiple files

Tags: java

I'm trying to read one file and write several files after modifying a small point.

My code works while writing the first file, but the other files are empty files. :(

I think there is a problem when I use `bufferedwriter` and `filewriter`, but can't find what the problem is though I followed an advice to use `flush` from stackoverflow.

What is the problem in my code?

```
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(FileDir);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        for (String mc: matchedContents){
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(saveFileDir+String.valueOf(matchedContents.indexOf(mc)+1)+".xml", false);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            while ((s = br.readLine())!=null){
                // check if s has matched contents
                if (s.contains(mc)){
                    String replacedString="";
                    if (mc.contains("NV"))
                        replacedString = s.replace(mc, "NV("+anyItem(edgeNames)+")");
                    else if (mc.contains("AW"))
                        replacedString = s.replace(mc, "AW("+anyItem(edgeNames)+")");
                    bw.write(replacedString);
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                else {
                    bw.write(s);
                    bw.newLine();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(mc+" end");
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
```

Comment: try and use that magically thing called a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because after the first file your `bufferedReader` comes to the end. To write again you need to reload the file to `bufferedReader`. So what you need to do is make the `bufferedReader` and the `FileReader` inside the for loop

```
    for (String mc: matchedContents){
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(FileDir);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(saveFileDir+String.valueOf(matchedContents.indexOf(mc)+1)+".xml", false);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        while ((s = br.readLine())!=null){
            // check if s has matched contents
            if (s.contains(mc)){
                String replacedString="";
                if (mc.contains("NV"))
                    replacedString = s.replace(mc, "NV("+anyItem(edgeNames)+")");
                else if (mc.contains("AW"))
                    replacedString = s.replace(mc, "AW("+anyItem(edgeNames)+")");
                bw.write(replacedString);
                bw.newLine();
            }
            else {
                bw.write(s);
                bw.newLine();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(mc+" end");
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
        br.close();
    }

    fr.close();
```

Comment: Thanks!! but `FileReader fr = new FileReader(FileDir);` should be in for loop too.. or, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would try debugging the code line by line and check what is exactly being written to the second, third etc. file (maybe the file writing is OK, but empty strings are being written?).

Also check:

[Debugging Java code line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754511/debugging-java-code-line-by-line) 
[Java read in single file and write out multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543053/java-read-in-single-file-and-write-out-multiple-files)